# Applications lost after transfer from memory card

Tags: file-transfer, memory-card

I connected my phone using mass storage and copied all the folders from memory card to pc to transfer on another memord card. But after that, I couldn't find some applications and nokia maps wasn't working correctly. I did the exact copy but still what am i missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I did the exact copy but still what am i missing here?

You probably didn't copy everything. Here are some ideas:

- Check for hidden files and folders. Make sure you set Windows Explorer to show you these as well. Then repeat the copy process.
- A hidden partition not exposed through the phone's USB mass storage connection. You would need to make a 1:1 copy of the SD card's partitions, using a USB card reader.
- You could try to [make an image](http://www.imgburn.com/) of your SD card partition and restore it to the other one. I guess this only works though if the SD card has one partition or if you have direct access to it.

Also note that I found [this answer](http://discussions.europe.nokia.com/t5/Other-Nokia-Phones/6300-SD-Card-cant-transfer-all-files-to-backup/td-p/108273) in a forum:

> No installed software on memory cards can be copied over.

This basically means you should move the apps to the phone before copying the SD card,  then moving them back onto your new SD card.